# bootstrap - multiple questions concerning twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been looking through some of the answers providing to some of the questions users have asked concerning twitter bootstrap but they do not necessaryily answer my issues. I have several questions concerning bootstrap and any help would be appreciated, thanks.

1. Footer
   How do I produce a footer that spans the whole width of the screen (despite screen resolution) and stays at the bottom of the page. When I search for this I get people providing code for sticky footers (footers that hoover with the page), and saying use absolute positioning (which I hear is a no no). A perfect example of what I mean is the one of the sites twitter bootstrap cites as an example (https://www.gathercontent.com/). On that site the footer (which looks like a hero unit or something) is always on the bottom of the page.
2. Container
   My twitter bootstrap container is shifted to the left for some reason. Is there any way to make it take up the whole screen despite resolution? When I use .container-fluid, it seems to shrink the overall container (even when I add .row-fluid to all my rows).
3. Alerts
   My alerts are not increasing in width. That is to say that I would like the alert (background color and all) to be the width of the container. In the link below I would like "If this is your ad login to edit" to span the whole container. However when I try .span12 it just shifts the alert. Also width:100%; does nothing to help. Also when I press login and an a login error occurs the error is shown at the far left instead of right on top of the login form.

*** concerning items 2 and 3 refer to this link https://twitter.com/HassanNSaid/status/355797180063301632/photo/1 ***

1. Popover
   Is there any way to shift the popover if it nears the end of the page? That is to say that if the popover occurs to the right, if your are as far right as possible then it should pop left. ***Sorry I did not search for this one just yet, its a new issue that has arisen***

Agian sorry for asking so many questions in one thread but I figured it would be better to not waste space with multiple threads. Thanks for any help.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with position:absolute;

Comment: Your question can easily seen as too broad as defined in the [help] pages. It might have been better to ask separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how this helps,
For footer, have a look here: https://gist.github.com/martinbean/1855032

As for the rest, everything seems, fine, error messages go the full width of the loging box etc.